# how can i get html anchor tag id attribute in python function in flask

Tags: python, flask

part of html script:

```
<a href="/author_profile" id="{{record[0]}}">{{record[1]}}</a>
```

python code:

```
@app.route('/author_profile')
  def author_profile():
     id=request.args['id']
     return render_template('author_profile.html',id=id)
```

how can I get the id of anchor tag in the flask module?

Answer (score 1):

Add an `<int:id>` parameter to the route, and use `url_for` to generate a URL to it with the id value.

```html
<a href="{{ url_for('author_profile', id=record[0]">{{record[1]}}</a>
```

```py
@app.route('/author_profile/<int:id>')
def author_profile(id):
    author = Author.query.get(id)
    return render_template('author_profile.html', author=author)
```