# Return Id of clicked a tag

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, flask

I use flask to show SQL table in html page like:

> .html page:

```
    <tbody>
    {% for row in myresultt %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
        <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
        <td>{{row[4]}}</td>
        <td class="pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            <i class="fas fa-eye text-gray px-1"></i>
            10
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%;">
            <ul class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <li class="mx-1">
                    <button class="btn gold-color-bg white-color font-12">
                        <a class="text-white" id="button" name="button" value="{{ row[0] }}" href="{{ url_for('join_s_mod')}}">start</a>
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

screenshot of HTML page

[image: img1]

screenshot of database table

[image: img2]

> .py code:

```
@flask.route('/next_lecture', methods=['POST'])
def join_s_mod():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        button= request.form['button']
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `sessioncreate` WHERE `ownerId` = %s', str(button))
    myresult = cursor.fetchall()
return render_template("next-lecturee.html", myresultt=myresult)
```

I need when I click start button of HTML page returns id of row and pass this id value to SQL query as variable.

Comment: if you can use  `GET` method than you pass it through `url_for` [link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#url-building) [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58642110/how-can-i-get-html-anchor-tag-id-attribute-in-python-function-in-flask)

Comment: @gaurav I tried pass it like {{ url_for('join_s_mod'), id=row[0]}} but returns error

Comment: error coming from flask function or pymysql ? you shoudl use tuple in execute function like `cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM sessioncreate WHERE ownerId = %s', (id,))`  [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

Answer (score 1):

try using this, ive never had problems with it myself, been using it since HTML 15.3

```
<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B1</button>
<button id="2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B2</button>
<button id="3" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B3</button>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
  function reply_click(clicked_id)
  {
      alert(clicked_id);
  }
</script>
```